# I'm new to maven and I'm getting this error while Creating an Adobe CQ archetype project

Tags: maven, aem

> Failed to execute goal
>
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2 rate (default-cli)
> on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does st
> (com.day.jcr.vault:multimodule-content-package-archetype:1.0.0)

Please help and provide me a link to understand creating project using maven

Answer (score 0):

Its not that easy to find out what the exact problem is, but the keyword multi module content package says that something is wrong with your project hierarchy or with transitive dependencies. When you can tell us about your project hierarchy oder explain a little more in detail, how your project is structured, it would be easier to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the syntax of all the parameters is right. I just tried the below command on my system and it worked fine.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/ -DarchetypeGroupId=com.day.jcr.vault -DarchetypeArtifactId=multimodule-content-package-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2 -DgroupId=my-group-id -DartifactId=myproject -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.mycompany.myproject -DappsFolderName=myproject -DartifactName="My Project" -DcqVersion="5.6.1" -DpackageGroup="My Company"
```

Comment: Also if one is behind corporate proxy (which blocks external URLs), the dependency or archetype download might not work, appropriate entries need to be added to settings.xml [link](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for maven.